# Debug custom plugin error

Tags: installation, custom-module

I am developing few plugins for Joomla 3. 
I've done so far 4 of them. The first 3 works flawlessy, but the latest one gives me this error during the installation:

```
 500 Installation unexpectedly terminated: Plugin Install: No plugin file specified
```

I've checked 10 times the xml comparing it with the other plugins. Everything seems in place. Joomla doesn't tell me anything else, so I'm a bit lost.

How can I get better and deeper debug informations so I'm able to solve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you get mentions the obvious. That in your xml file you haven't specified the plugin.php file. Make sure you have included the correct php file of the plugin in the files section of the xml file.

```
<filename plugin="myplugin">myplugin.php</filename>
```

Example:

```
<files>
    <filename plugin="myplugin">myplugin.php</filename>
    <filename>other_files.php</filename>
    <filename>index.html</filename>
    ...
</files>
```

Comment: I am so blind. The line was there, but I wrote module="myplugin" instead of plugin="myplugin" and I was comparing it with a module extension, so I didn't notice the error.